# Receiving nan as output

Tags: python

I have the followig code, but I keep receiving 'nan' as output in my rnorm and actRnorm lists, as a result I cannot plot the values. Does anyone have any tips?

```
def conjugatGradient(A,b,n):
  x = b
  r = b - A*x
  p = r
  r_old = r.conj().T*r

  rnorm = []
  actRnorm = []
  estimate = []
  
  for i in range(n):
    Ap = A*p
    alpha = r_old/(p.conj().T*Ap)
    x = x + alpha*p
    r = r - alpha*Ap
    r_new = r.conj().T*r
    if np.sqrt(r_new).any() < 1e-10:
      break
    p = r + (r_new/r_old)*p
    r_old = r_new
    
    rnorm.append(np.linalg.norm(r))
    actRnorm.append(np.linalg.norm(b-A*x))
    estimate.append(2*((np.sqrt(np.linalg.cond(A))-1)/(np.sqrt(np.linalg.cond(A))+1))**i)

  plt.plot(rnorm)
  plt.plot(actRnorm)
  plt.plot(estimate)
  plt.show()
```

With A and b as follows:

```
A = np.diag(range(1,101))
for i in range(1,100):
  A[i-1,i] = 1
  A[i,i-1] = 1

b = np.ones(100)
```

I am hoping to get a plot with estimats, rnorm and actRnorm on it, but right now it is only printing estimates.

Comment: Are you looking at the errors and warnings?  You get divide by zero errors when computing `r.conj()`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: That doesn't sound right. Taking a complex conjugate involves no division. Are you sure the warning is coming from where you think it's coming from?

Comment: You're right, it's from the `r_old/(p.conj().T*Ap)` computation.

Comment: @TimRoberts do you know how I would fix that, if I use the following matrix A and vector b, from my understanding, I should be getting a zero value. I added the matrix A and vector b to the original question

Comment: You should print your intermediate values.  In the first loop, `p` and `p.conj()` look fine, but `r_old` is mostly zeros, so `r_new/r_old` produces mostly `nan`s, and that continues.  I DO get a plot, but I don't know how meaningful it is.